# How can I apply a unique value to column A for rows with common values in column A

Tags: google-sheets

I want to name certain groups of values with a unique identifier in the `Column B`.

I have two columns. How can I apply a unique value to `column B` for rows with common values in column A.

For example, any row with `6001, 6010, 6020, 6041` in `column A` should show a unique identifier in `column B`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bVCal7914W9wAOmbqwXpuJFSZ_cXuhm2l_j5GENxzVY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share an example in your sheet for column B

Comment: I added an example 
6001, 6010, 6020, 6040 = Group A &

8001, 8011, 8020, 8041 = Group B

Comment: there are 125 groups so what do you want to do after Group Z ? Group AA ?

Comment: I did not consider that sorry. I would use numbers. I changed the example on the spreadsheet to Group 1 and Group 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), 
 "Group "&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A)))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]